# Getting (530) not Logged in when trying to access IIS with host name instead of IP

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-7.5

I have set up an FTP site on Windows Server 2008 (IIS 7.5). Anonymous authentication is enabled while Basic authentication is not. I've added a rule that allows all anonymous users to Read. In the Bindings for the port 21 I've specified `testftp.com` as host name. In the hosts file I've added line
`127.0.0.1 testftp.com`. Now, I try to access it in two ways:

1. From Internet Explorer. I get "This page can't be displayed" message.
2. From C# code:

   ```csharp
   string ftpFilePath="ftp://testftp.com/sample.txt";
   FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpFilePath);
   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
   request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "password@testftp.com");
   ```

   This way I get `(530) Not logged in` error.

Now, If I remove the host name from bindings and hosts file and access it with IP address I can read files without any problem. Is there any configuration I need to consider to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have misunderstood the point of the binding settings.

It's not to bind a hostname to the IP address.

It's to bind the FTP site to the IP address and hostname (separately).

---

The *host name* box is not actually related to the IP address binding at all. It's allows you to bind multiple FTP sites (instances) to the same IP address, yet allowing the FTP server to differentiate, what site the client wanted to connect to (similarly to virtual HTTP hosting). The client needs to use `HOST hostname` command to choose (similarly to HTTP/1.1 `Host` header).

I believe that the `FtpWebRequest` does use `HOST` command. So the FTP server is not able to tell what FTP site you connect to, hence it fails the authentication.

You can workaround that using a special (IIS-specific) username syntax `"HOST|USERNAME"`.

But as I've wrote at the beginning, I believe you actually didn't want to restrict the FTP site to the hostname.

If you clear the hostname box, the FTP server does not require the `HOST` command.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure but this seems to be one of those stupid IIS bugs. I tried clearing the host name in bindings and guess what, it worked.